# Library not registered

Tags: vb.net

I got this error :

> ```
>  Warning  1   Cannot get the file path for type library
>  "a5ededf4-2bbc-45f3-822b-e60c278a1a79" version 12.0. Library not
>  registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D
>  (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))   OCRMongo
> ```

In vb.net

I follow instruction from 
http://www.techrepublic.com/forum/questions/101-345154/how-do-i-install-microsoft-modi-110

and I still get that warning. What's the problem?

Comment: Is it registered properly using regsvr32?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with existing COM Reference or adding a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237766/error-with-existing-com-reference-or-adding-a-new-one)